# Почему появляется непонятная кракозябра?

Tags: php, html, css

[image]

Что за кракозябра появилась??? В чем проблема? Использую одинаковые коды практически. Вот первая колонка(код):

```
<table border="0" class="table_size" align="left">
 <tr><td>
 <?php
    include("db.php");

 do {
printf("
        <table border='1' class='table_size'>
            <tr>
                <td class='table_cover'>%s</td>
                <td>
                    <table border='0' width='100%%'>
                        <tr class='table_first_row'>
                            <td>%s</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>%s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>" , $row['cover'], $row['title'], $row['audio'] );
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 ?>
 </td></tr>
```

Вот код второй таблицы, где появляется сама кракозябра:

```
<table border="0" class="table_size" align="center">
 <tr><td>
 <?php
include("db2.php");

 do {
printf("
        <table border='1' class='table_size'>
            <tr>
                <td class='table_cover'>%s</td>
                <td>
                    <table border='0' width='100%%'>
                        <tr class='table_first_row'>
                            <td>%s</td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>%s</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>" , $row['cover'], $row['title'], $row['audio'] );
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
 ?>
 </td></tr>
```

Comment: win1251 utf-8

Comment: А как хорошо видно-то, что внутри голубенького пятнышка! И бинокля не надо :)

Comment: какая тебе разница что там? разбираешься в кракозябрах? @klopp

Comment: Что такое  

    width='100%%'
? Зачем два процентика? Мне для саморазвития.

Comment: Может быть `db2.php` сохранена в UTF8 + BOM ?  
Пересохраните без BOM попробуйте.

Comment: А что в db2.php?